# Outlook message window partially freezing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, remote-desktop, microsoft-office

I have a Windows 10 PRO INTEL NUC computer with MS Office Home&Business 2019 installed and I use 2 4K displays (one connected via display port and another via hdmi cable).

I'm connecting to my work computer with Windows Remote Desktop. My work computer is a HP Elite Workstation with the same Windows & MS Office installed.

Bot computers are fully updated (Windows, Office and hardware drivers).

For a couple of months now I'm experiencing problems with Outlook message window. It often happens that part of the window acts like is frozen (can't click on anything or can't select text from the body of the message), but on the other hand part of the window works just fine (for example the menus).

As I'm writing this post I'm writting a new email and the status of the message window is:

- frozen/irresponsive: message body (text), ribbon/menu
- working: from, to and cc fields

The same happens on both computers - either I'm using Office on local computer either over RDP.

I have no similar problems whatsoever with other Office products (Excel, Word).

Any ideas what could be the issue?

**EDIT (Feb 4th 2022):**
the same problem with a new work computer from last week (HP EliteDesk)!

EDIT (FEB 9 2022): added print screen
[image]

Comment: Any dialogue boxes in the background?

Comment: no, just "basic" Outlook window in the back and new/reply/forward message window in the front

Comment: Does this happen if you [Open Outlook in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-outlook-in-safe-mode-f394c2ee-b2af-e97a-64ee-35cd24414811)? If it doesn't happen, then the problem is with some add-in.

Comment: 1)Does it eventually resolve itself and/or how do you overcome the error (ex: closing Outlook with task manager)? 2)Try unplugging your keyboard when it happens (curious if a button is getting stuck or stuck-on in RDP) & report results. 3)Can you do a [screen capture](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/record-desktop-using-vlc) to show us?
I echo harrymc's suggestion of trying Outlook safe mode

Comment: It's my work computer so I couldn't check during the weekend. So (1) I will test in safe mode and come back to you (2) when it happens I just close Outlook completely and restart it and it's usually OK for some time.

Comment: note: after closing Outlook sometime I can not restart it - Outlook kinda "lingers on" so I have to manually kill the process in Task manager and then I can start it again

Comment: still testing in safe mode. About (3) screen capture want show much because everything look normal it's just that you can not click it...

Comment: So this is still happening in safe mode? Does it happen when working directly from your work computer? If this is happening on several computers, perhaps the problem is with the server.

Comment: I'm testing in safe mode today. So far it's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the problem does not arrive when
[running Outlook in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-outlook-in-safe-mode-f394c2ee-b2af-e97a-64ee-35cd24414811),
the problem is likely due to some installed add-in.

Disable the add-ins in menu *File > Options > Add-ins* until you find
the problem. You may then either leave it disabled, or look for a newer
version of this add-in that does not cause such problems.

---

This manipulation has fixed the problem (for the moment):
Run Outlook as Administrator, exit and restart in normal mode.

Sometimes apparently Office gets itself tied up in a permissions
knot, so needs administrator permissions to effect the blocked
operation. Running Office (Word, Excel etc) once as administrator
sets it in order.

Comment: if you look at my comment (Apr 13 2021 at 18:09) under the answer from JeffYang7 you can see that the problem on my previous (new) work computer appeared also on fresh Office install without any add-ons... I will test further and let you know

Comment: OK, I have disabled the only add-in we use for Outlook and restarted Outlook. And the problem just happened again. This time on color picker. Everything else works I just cannot select/click on any of the colors.

Comment: I have added a print screen to my original question (above)

Comment: We cried victory too soon... Here is a manipulation that sometimes helped : Run Outlook as Administrator, exit and restart in normal mode.

Comment: OK, just did. I will test and report.

Comment: This last suggestion ("... Run Outlook as Administrator, exit and restart in normal mode ...") seemed to help. Haven't had the problem since. Thank you!

Comment: *I missed the bounty deadline. Is there a way to still award it?

Comment: No, it's lost for good. Note that if in the future an answer seems like a good candidate for the bounty, you may mark it as accepted. You can always later transfer the mark to another and better answer, but the bounty will be automatically awarded if you miss the deadline.

Comment: OK, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fully repair your Outlook client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to ensure the features of client itself can all work fine.

From the perspective of the Outlook client, there could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

By the way, have you enabled hardware graphics acceleration in Outlook? If yes, I would suggest you to check the ["disable hardware graphics acceleration" option](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4432-outlook-disable-hardware-graphics-acceleration.html) to turn off the Hardware Acceleration completely will run the application in software rendering mode’ and see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Tried all of this before. Problem even happens on a fresh install of Windows and Office (no addons)

Comment: Weird! Have not met issues like this yet. Can everything work fine before? Is this an issue that only happen after Office updates?

Comment: This is an issue I'm only experiencing either on Intel NUC directly or using NUC for Remote desktop to my work computer. It's present both on my old NUC (app 3 years) and my brand new one.

Comment: And, on both of them the problem started sometime this January so I'm thinking maybe it could be related to some of NUC drivers (update)...

Comment: Well, sounds like it might indeed be one of the possible factor. What about trying some old version drivers and see how the issue goes?

Comment: Only graphic drivers or also something else?

Comment: Graphic Drivers could be the first, the NUC Drivers may be also worth a shot?

Comment: I just got a brand new NUC two days ago and I have the same problem... This is really strange.

Comment: Me again with the same problem. Unbelievably but I have a new work computer from last week (HP EliteDesk) and I have the same problem with Outlook. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be interesting to analyze a process dump of Outlook.exe when the process is in this state.  I would be inclined to take 2 or 3 so as to check on the progress of threads between snapshots.  I don't know if you would want to share dumps though.

Comment: Can't share dumps - work computer & emails.